# XAML - Comma-Delimited Dependency Property

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom class called AppPreferences. This class has a dependency property called Color. This dependency property represents an enumerated value of the type Colors (which is a custom enumerator). My code for AppPreferences is shown here:

```
public class AppPreferences
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "Color",
  typeof(MyServiceProxy.Colors),
  typeof(AppPreferences),
  new PropertyMetadata(MyServiceProxy.Colors.DEFAULT, new   PropertyChangedCallback(OnColorChanged))
  );

  private static void OnColorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Do Stuff
  }
}
```

As a developer, I add this to my UI elements to help determine the color. For instance, I'll do something like this:

```
<TextBox custom:AppPreferences.Color="Black" ... />
```

I now have a need to support fallback colors. In other words, I want to be able to provide a comma-delimited list of Colors values similar to the following:

```
<TextBox custom:AppPreferences.Color="Black,Blue" ... />
```

My question is, how do I update my dependency property and OnColorChanged event handler to support multiple values?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [wpf dependency property enum collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714193/wpf-dependency-property-enum-collection)

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism you're trying to achieve is called "Attached properties".

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) for info.

Here is a short code excerpt that does it all:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBubbleSourceProperty = 
 DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "IsBubbleSource",
  typeof(Boolean),
  typeof(AquariumObject),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender)
);
public static void SetIsBubbleSource(UIElement element, Boolean value)
{
  element.SetValue(IsBubbleSourceProperty, value);
}
public static Boolean GetIsBubbleSource(UIElement element)
{
  return (Boolean)element.GetValue(IsBubbleSourceProperty);
}
```

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723.aspx#ctl00_MTCS_main_ctl187_ctl00_ctl08) to get more on comma-separated enumerations in Xaml.

Also you may want checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714193/wpf-dependency-property-enum-collection).

Answer (score 0):

You should [ensure that you have a flagwise enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723.aspx#ctl00_MTCS_main_ctl187_ctl00_ctl08) in order to allow this syntax. This is possible by adding the [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) to your enumeration.

```
[Flags]
enum Colors
{
    Black,
    ...
}
```

> For flagwise enumerations, the behavior is based on the Enum.Parse
>   method. You can specify multiple values for a flagwise enumeration by
>   separating each value with a comma. However, **you cannot combine
>   enumeration values that are not flagwise**. For instance, you cannot use
>   the comma syntax to attempt to create a Trigger that acts on multiple
>   conditions of a nonflag enumeration.