# WPF Dependency Property as Enum Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, dependency-properties

I have a enum like this:

```
public enum Filter
{
   Filter1,
   Filter2,
   Filter3,
   Filter4
}
```

And I would like to use like this:

```
<local:myComponent FilterList={Filter.Filter1, Filter.Filter2} />
```

I was trying to use this: [wpf dependency property enum collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714193/wpf-dependency-property-enum-collection) but it didin't work as I expected.
I don't want the user to type freely, I want them to use the list of enum.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** In case your `FilterList` is a collection... Well, it shouldn't. Or better said, it doesn't have to be a collection and it would just adds complexity to make it one.

Enums can be used as Flags, which means that you can set multiple values to a single Enum property as long as you observe some special considerations.

Check this artcile in the MSDN for more info about Flag Enumerations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229062(v=vs.100).aspx

And this for more info: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/396851/Ending-the-Great-Debate-on-Enum-Flags

But, basically, you should define your enum as follows:

```
public enum Filter
{
   Filter1 = 1,
   Filter2 = 2,
   Filter3 = 4,
   Filter4 = 8
}
```

Then define your FilterList property as of type `Filter` only, **not a collection**.

```
public Filter FilterList
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

Once you've done that, you can set the property from XAML as follows:

```
<local:myComponent FilterList="Filter1, Filter2" />
```

Check this article for more info: http://blog.martinhey.de/en/post/2012/06/13/Flagged-enums-and-XAML-syntax.aspx

And you can set it and check it programatically using simple bitwise operations.

Setting:

```
FilterList = Filter.Filter1 | Filter.Filter2;
```

Checking:

```
if ((FilterList & Filter.Filter3) == Filter.Filter3)
```

...or...

```
if (FilterList.HasFlag(Filter.Filter3))
```

Comment: It worked programatically, but when I try to set from XAML (<local:myComponent FilterList="Filter1, Filter2" />), the property don't allow the comma or even space between the enum items. It gives only the Enum options and I can set just once.

Comment: Maybe setting the `[Flags]` attribute in your enum? I'll try it and come back to you

Comment: Weird... The code in my example, without the Flags attributes, works just fine for me... Did you set the enum values as powers of two, as I did? (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.)

Comment: And even more important... Did you change your FilterList property to make it of type Filter only, instead of a collection?

Comment: I did exactly as you said, my enum is setted 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64..... And I did change the property to type Filter only. I don't know what could be wrong :(

Comment: Neither do I :/ I'm clueless now... Maybe if you could show us more of your code... Because it should be working, there must be something we're overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `FilterList` is a collection of Filter enum items, does it work to define them like this in your XAML?

```
<local:myComponent>
    <FilterList>
        <x:Static local:Filter.Filter1 />
        <x:Static local:Filter.Filter2 />
    </FilterList>
</local:myComponent>
```

I'm not really sure of a shorter way of writing that except perhaps a Converter to convert a csv string to an enum list.